# How to uninstall redis on Centos 8

Tags: redis, malware, centos8

How can i fully uninstall redis from my Centos 8 machine ?

I have a malware that keeps getting in via redis

```
41533 redis     20   0 5883224   4.4g   2776 S  1593  13.9  13507:24 kdevtmpfsi
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you think your server is compromised, then you should really rebuild the entire server. See [How do I deal with a compromised server?](https://serverfault.com/questions/218005/how-do-i-deal-with-a-compromised-server).

As for the application(s) running redis and redis itself, I would also highly recommend that you spend the time securing it rather than simply removing it. It may be that you have a dependency.

You can do a `dnf info redis` to confirm that it is currently installed with dnf:

```
[root@support]# dnf info redis | grep -A3 ": redis"
Name         : redis
Version      : 5.0.3
Release      : 1.module_el8.0.0+6+ab019c03
Architecture : x86_64
```

If you don't need redis, and it is currently installed with `dnf`, then you can simply remove it with dnf:

`dnf remove redis`

However, as I mentioned, it's very possible that you have some sort of dependency that requires it. If this is the case, then you'll need to secure redis and your application(s) instead.

Comment: no i don't have any dependency thanks